# Cut awk field value

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, system-administration

I have this "answer section" from a `dig` call:

```
www.google.com 300 IN A \<ip_address\>
```

I want to extract the sub-domain `www` out of the `www.google.com` to save in a variable.

I have tried to use `sed` to filter out the sub-domain name, then replace field one (i.e. `$1`), after passing to `awk`, with `$host_name`, like so:

```
host_name=$(echo get_dig "$@" | sed 's/..*//; s/ .*//')
...
get_dig "$@" | awk '{ $1 = $host_name; printf("The subdomain %s is a %s record and points to %s\\n", $1, $4, $5) }'
```

**N.B:** `get_dig` is a shell function I created to run `dig` and extract the "answer section".

I have tested and the `sed` part cuts as I expect it to and gives the correct result (i.e. `www`), but when I try to replace `$1` with `$host_name`, it seems to alter the behaviour and returns the whole `dig` "answer section" as the hostname in the `printf` string. Also, I have `$hostname` declared globally.

**PS:** I have to use awk, but it's possible that I might have tunnel-visioned into a particular process, with `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need sed when you're using awk. I think this is what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
echo 'www.google.com 300 IN A \<ip_address\>' |
awk '{
    sub(/\..*/,"",$1);
    printf "The subdomain %s is a %s record and points to %s\n", $1, $4, $5
}'
The subdomain www is a A record and points to \<ip_address\>
```

Replace the `echo '...'` with `get_dig "$@"` (which I obviously don't have).

As for why your script didn't work, see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and get rid of the `echo` in front of `get_dig` in the pipe to `sed`.

Comment: Your answer worked great and produced the desired output. It saved me from having to use `sed` and keeping track of another variable, so thanks for that!

I did a lot of reading into `awk` because of this, but somehow, I did not come across this `sub` function. Is there an `awk` documentation that you could refer me to, so I can read more on sub and the other `awk` functions.

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins but `sub()` is described in every awk man page, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html, so I'm not sure what documentation you were looking at that didn't have it but get rid of that documentation. It's also described in the POSIX awk spec, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html.

Comment: **after you buy the book**, you can also use the associated reference material at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ $1 = $host_name; printf("The subdomain %s is a %s record and points to %s\\n", $1, $4, $5) }'
```

You are attempting to access `host_name`th field of line, if you wish to use shell variable inside `awk` command you should ram it using one of

```
-v var=val
--assign var=val
```

Consider following simple example

```
host_name="www"
echo "uno dos tres" | awk -v host_name="$host_name" '{$1=host_name; printf("Subdomain %s is %s and points to %s\n",$1,$2,$3)}'
```

gives output

```
Subdomain www is dos and points to tres
```

Note: I use `echo "uno dos tres"` as stand-in for your command.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna extract fields out of `dig`'s response, here's a quick way to split it out. The formatting is trivial from here on :

```
dig +noall +answer www.google.com | 
                                    gtee >( gcat -n >&2; ) |
```

---

```
     1  www.google.com.     112 IN  A   142.250.80.36
```

---

```
mawk NF=NF FS='[.][^ \t]+[ \t]+|[ \t].+[ \t]' OFS='\f'
```

---

```
www
   112
      142.250.80.36
```